# Conditional Formatting in SSRS

Tags: date, reporting-services, formatting, conditional-statements

I am a bit new with SSRS, I need to do a conditional formatting in SSRS, where if the last_backup_date is less than 3 days, the column will be "Yellow" and if it is less than 7 days, then the column will be "Red"... I can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. I tried using Switch function but just can't figure out which Date & Time function to use here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
=Switch(
DATEDIFF(DateinterVal.Day,Fields!last_backup_date,Today())<3,"Yellow",
DATEDIFF(DateinterVal.Day,Fields!last_backup_date,Today())<7,"Red"
)
```

### Update

Adding an additional condition based on comments.

```
=Switch(
DATEDIFF(DateinterVal.Day,Fields!last_backup_date,Today())<3,"DarkGreen",
DATEDIFF(DateinterVal.Day,Fields!last_backup_date,Today())<=7,"Yellow",
true,"Red"
)
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was magic...thanks a bunch for your help. Worked perfectly.

Comment: So i was going thru the report result, but only problem I am seeing is if the last_backup_date is exactly 7 days old, then i am getting RED, but if it's more than 7 days old (like 8 days or 15 days or a month), i am getting just white. Also, i want dark green for the ones whose last_backup_was taken within 3 days (not more than 3 days).

Comment: @NahidSultanaTithi, I've updated the expression, give it a try.

Comment: I am getting DARK GREEN for the rows that had backup taken more than 7 days ago (it should be RED if it's more than 7 days).                                                 But i Do want DARK GREEN for the rows that had backup taken in last 3 days.

Comment: @NahidSultanaTithi, I've updated the second expression give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Alejandro, i think i will stick to the previous color codes, for some reason that's giving me the result i want. I really appreciate your help and time.